# how to show a direct sum of two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, direct-sum

Let $U,V$ two subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$, such that:
$U = \{x \in \mathbb R^n | x_1+x_2+...+x_n=0\}$ and $V=\{x\in V |x_1=x_2=...=x_n\}$

Show that the sum of the two subspaces is a direct sum.

**What I did:**
We want to show that $U\cap V = \{0\}$. 
Indeed, let $w \in U\cap V$, Hence:

$w_1 = w_2 = ...  = w_n$
$w_1 + w_2 + ... + w_n = 0.$

it's easy to see that $\forall i.w_i = 0$, Therefore it's the zero vector.

Now, for my understanding this isn't suffice in order to show it's a direct sum.
We also need to prove that $U+V = \mathbb{R}^n$.

Is it right? How to do that?

Comment: Just to make it a bit clear, we usually say that a space $V$ is a direct sum of two spaces $M$ and $N$ if  $V=M+N$ and $M\cap N=\emptyset$.... so there is some gap in between... do you want to say that your direct sum $U$ with $V$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$ or just the sum is direct sum (with no mention regarding the resultant)?

Comment: Good point. I need to show that $\mathbb{R}^n=U\oplus V$.

Comment: so... what do you want do do now?

Comment: I want to understand if it is suffice to show the intersection is the zero vector.

Comment: It is not sufficient... One possibly better way is to check for dimensions and add them up (do not forget to thank $U\cap V=\emptyset$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to do that. The task is to prove that $U+V$ is a direct sum, that is what you showed. As far as you wrote, you don't have to prove that $U+V = \mathbb R$.

If you do want to prove that, look at the dimension of $U$ and $V$. Because $U\cap V = 0$, you know that dim$(U+V) = $ dim$(U)+$dim$(V)$.

If you do not yet have the theoretical background to make the dimension argument, then take ant $x\in\mathbb R^n$ and look at $\tilde x$ defined as $\tilde x_i =x_i - \bar x$ where $\bar x$ is the average value of values $x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n$.

Comment: Trying to interrupt your words; it's suffice to show the intersection is only the zero vector. Right?

Comment: To prove that $U+V$ is a direct sum of $U$ and $W$, yes. If you must prove that $\mathbb R^n = U⊕V$, see the second part of my answer.

Comment: What is $W$ exactly?

Comment: Sorry. Replace all $W$s with $V$s.

Comment: But theoretically, how do you know for sure that there isn't $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $v \notin V \wedge v \notin U$

Comment: Because $U+V$ is a $n$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^n$. If $M$ and $N$ are vector spaces and $M\subseteq N$ and the dimension of $M$ is equal to the dimension of $N$, then $M=N$.

Comment: I added a hint if you cannot yet use the argument with the dimensions (if you haven't covered that).

Comment: I do familiar with this theorem but I must ask again; How do you that $dim(U+V) = n$?

Comment: Because $\dim(U) = n-1$ (the base is $(1,0,\dots, 0, -1), (0,1,0,\dots, 0,-1)$ and so on) and $\dim(V) = 1$ (spanned by $(1,1,\dots,1)$).

Answer (score 1):

The theorem:

Let $U, W$ are subspaces of V.

Then $U + W$ is a direct sum $\iff U\cap W = \{0\}$.

The proof:

Suppose "$U + W$ is a direct sum" is true.

Then $v \in U, w \in W$ such that $0 = v+w$. And since $U + W$ is a direct sum $v = w =0$ by the theorem **"Condition for a direct sum"**. Thus, $U\cap W = \{0\}$ is true.

Suppose that "$U\cap W = \{0\}$" is true.

Then, in order to proof that $U + W$ is a direct sum, just need to show that $v \in U, w \in W$ such that $0 = v + w$ where $v = 0$ and $w = 0$.

The equation $0 = v + w$ $\iff$ $v = -w$, where $-w \in W$ is true by property **"additive inverse"**. And hence $v \in U\cap W$ and $v = 0$ and by the equation above $w = 0$.

Comment: The $\Leftarrow$ of the theorem is not true. Take the x-axis and the y-axis as 1-dim subsapces of the 3-dim Euclidean space. Their intersection is $\{0\}$ but their direct sum is the xy plane and not the whole 3-d space.